# Compare and filter out date properties in a object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
    myObject = {
      publishedDate: string;
      Url: string;
      Title: string;
  }
```

The property "publishedDate" is a string in the format "19/01/2021". As the example, it can have a date in the future, i.e. a value greater than today. In other words I want to keep all objects where publishedDate is equal or less than today (and delete all that is over).
The objects is saved in my state (array):

```
this.state.data
```

I first make a date variable for todays value to compare it with publishedDate. I also use moment() to format it in the same date format as the object:

```
let today = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

I then use a filter method to compare and filter out the data:

```
  this.state.data.filter(item => new Date(item.publishedDate) >= new Date(today))
```

And I have also tried:

```
  this.state.data.filter(function(item) {
    
      if (new Date(item.publishedDate) >= new Date(today)) {
        return false;
      }
    return true;
  });
```

Not only it does not work, I still have all the objects in the array and nothing is filtered out. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: `new Date("19/01/2021")` returns: `Invalid Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` constructor won't accept the format you are currently using, but it will recognize `MM/DD/YYYY` format. Moreover, `filter` retains the elements for which the function returns true, so you should be checking if the `Date` is less than or equal to the current `Date`.

```
const today = new Date;
this.state.data = this.state.data.filter(({publishedDate})=>{
    const [d, m, y] = publishedDate.split("/");
    return new Date(m + "/" + d + "/" + y) <= today;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `moment`'s inbuilt comparators like this

```
this.state.data.filter(item => moment(item.publishedDate,'DD/MM/YYYY').isSameOrAfter(today))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using moment's [String + Format initializer](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and [Is Same Or After](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/):

`this.state.data.filter(item => moment(item.publishedDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').isSameOrAfter())`

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, using a helper function `notAfterToday`, which takes a property name (in our case `'publishedDate'`) and returns a function which takes an object with that property name and reports whether that date is before or on the current date.

It does this by converting, say, the 18th day of December in 2020 into "20201218", and uses that string for the comparisons.  Note that one advantage of this is that it only calls the Date constructor once, for the initial calculation of today's date.

```js
const data = [{publishedDate: '18/12/2020', Url: 'http://example.com/1', Title: 'abc'}, {publishedDate: '19/01/2021', Url: 'http://example.com/2', Title: 'def'}, {publishedDate: '07/04/2014', Url: 'http://example.com/3', Title: 'ghi'}, {publishedDate: '19/07/2023', Url: 'http://example.com/4', Title: 'jkl'}, {publishedDate: '05/01/1966', Url: 'http://example.com/5', Title: 'mno'}, {publishedDate: '01/07/2041', Url: 'http://example.com/6', Title: 'pqr'}, {publishedDate: '08/05/2061', Url: 'http://example.com/7', Title: 'stu'}, {publishedDate: '10/08/1999', Url: 'http://example.com/8', Title: 'vwx'}]

const notAfterToday = (prop) => {
  const reorg = (date, [d, m, y] = date.split('/')) => y + m + d 
  const today = new Date()
  const compare = today .getFullYear() + 
                  String ((today .getMonth () + 1)) .padStart (2, '0') +
                  String (today .getDate ()) .padStart (2, '0')
  return (d) => compare >= reorg (d [prop])
}

console .log (data .filter (notAfterToday ('publishedDate')))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, `new Date("19/01/2021")` returns: `Invalid Date`.

This is a possible solution:

```
let today = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

this.state.data.filter(function(item) {
    const pubDate = item.publishedDate.split('/').reverse().join('-');
    if (new Date(pubDate) >= new Date(today)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a little fine-tuning your date string before comparing with today. You can try this-

```js
const data = [
  {
    publishedDate: "19/01/2021",
    url: '',
    title: 'date1'
  },
  {
    publishedDate: "19/05/2021",
    url: '',
    title: 'date2'
  },
  {
    publishedDate: "13/01/2020",
    url: '',
    title: 'date3'
  },
  {
    publishedDate: "16/09/2009",
    url: '',
    title: 'date4'
  },
];

const parseDate = (dateString) => new Date(...dateString.split('/').reverse());


const result = data.filter(item => parseDate(item.publishedDate) <= new Date());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing dates as strings is a code smell. It's harder to compare, store, and convert them as opposed to storing them either as a JS native Date format, or alternatives like Moment.JS date object.

Here is a trivial example of how you could do it if you stored your objects as date.

Notice that the third object got filtered out.

```js
const myObject1 = {
  publishedDate: new Date("2019-01-01"), // NEW
  Url: "whatever",
  Title: "sample",
}

const myObject2 = {
  publishedDate: new Date("2020-01-01"), // NEW
  Url: "whatever",
  Title: "sample",
}

const myObject3 = {
  publishedDate: new Date("2099-01-01"), // NEW
  Url: "whatever",
  Title: "sample",
}

const arr = [myObject1, myObject2, myObject3];

const today = new Date();

const filtered = arr.filter((obj) => obj.publishedDate < today);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: On the contrary, strings serialize trivially, so they can be used in, for instance, JSON representations.  But an [appropriate format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) would be much more useful if the OP has control over the data structure.

Comment: I agree that strings are easily converted to JSON and are readable to humans. However, there are numerous downsides to storing dates as strings: it's hard to convert them, hard to ensure validity, harder date arithmetics, etc. See https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession

Comment: Remember that the OP started with "I have an object that looks like" with string formatted dates.  We both agree that the format is terrible, but I don't agree that a string format is unwarranted here.  I definitely think it better than the [strongly discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Timestamp_string) parsing of strings to make a new Date. I find [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) a useful middle-ground -- simple, sortable, serializable, relatively easy to convert to Date objects. If doing date math, I agree.